# What's the recommended way to deploy a Django app on IIS?

Tags: django, iis, azure

I've recently signed up for an Azure account as I am developing a Django application and porting it from Heroku. I've created a Windows Server 2012 vm on Azure and I've managed to copy my application and install its dependencies on the VM. I've also managed to run it directly on the command line. Now I'd like to run it under IIS. I've searched around the net and it seems there are many ways to skin this cat. I'd like to know the best way. Which approach would a professional who is deploying a production site use? I'm having a hard time finding out what the best approach is. The docs on the Django site are reportedly outdated and it points to another site which explains how to install Django with performance tools. The documentation on MSDN only includes tutorials that show installing under Windows and running from the command line or installing to an Ubuntu VM. I'm looking to get some guidance from someone who has done this and could explain the merits and weaknesses of one method over another. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at our FREE Windows Azure Web Sites offering? Web Sites supports Python as well as PHP, Node, ASP and ASP.NET.  There is even a tutorial there that describes how you can setup and run a Django website on our FREE hosting plan without the need for setting up your own VM. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/.  This doesn't really answer your question directly, so I listed it as a comment, but if it were me I'd be all over Windows Azure Web Sites if at all possible :-)

Comment: Thanx for the tip! I really didn't understand what the website option does nor did I take time to investigate. I may consider this as an alternative. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't know if it is recommended way or not but I followed this tutorial and succeded hosting Django with IIS without any problems https://nspointers.com/os/windows-server/deploy-django-web-on-iis/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the different options on the offical Windows Azure website:

- [Django Hello World Web Application](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-app-with-django/): This tutorial explains how you can install your Django application in IIS on a Virtual Machine. Note that this is IaaS, so if you want to want to use this for a production deployment you'll probably want to scale out. This means its up to you to add the required VMs, deploy your application on all these VMs, manage updates, manage security, ...
- [Creating Web Sites with Django](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/): This tutorial explains how to deploy your Django application to Windows Azure Web Sites. I think this is what you're looking for. The advantage here is that you can start free (shared with other websites, good for testing), then move to shared (still shared hosting, custom domain name, great for when you want to launch your app) and finally move to reserved (dedicated machine). The advantage here is that you can easily scale out, even to multiple reserved instances, without having to worry about deployment or managing the Virtual Machines. You can use Visual Studio or the Git/Bitbucket/TFS integration to deploy and Windows Azure Web Sites will make sure your site is deployed instantly (even if you're running in reserved mode with multiple instances)

Comment: Thanks Sandrino! I don't know how I overlooked the FastCGI section in the HelloWorld web app tutorial! Also, I will definitely consider the Azure websites option. I'm kicking the tires on Azure and I'm still puzzled over what I get with my MSDN ultimate subscription. I thought the virtual machine was included. I'm hoping I don't get charged for running it as I only deployed it while following one of the tutorials. Can I only run it for a set number of hours? At any rate, I think you've answered my question so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We've been at [DjangoCon](https://2015.djangocon.us/) this week helping people get Django Sites on Azure.

We've created a tutorial and repo to help people get started with a minimal amount of code.

- [Tutorial](http://djangocon.azurewebsites.net/)
- [Base Repo](https://github.com/timmyreilly/YourDjangoSiteResume)

Check out the forked projects to find some sweet examples attendees have made:

- [Batavia](http://batavia.azurewebsites.net/) - Python 3 in the Browser - [Repo](https://github.com/freakboy3742/batavia-azure)
- [Webcat](http://webcat.azurewebsites.net/webcat) - Ascii Kittens in the Browser - [Repo](https://github.com/cackovic/YourDjangoSiteResume)
- [DJReader](http://djreader.azurewebsites.net) - Reader Clone - [Repo](https://github.com/dcwatson/reader/tree/azure)
- [Health Recommendations](http://djangocon-us-2015.azurewebsites.net/) - [Repo](https://github.com/karthikbgl/YourDjangoSiteResume)

Comment: Tim, I have a similar query regarding hosting a Django app on Azure, except I want a Postgres database to go with it. How do I do that? (linked to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919732/how-to-migrate-a-django-web-app-from-heroku-to-azure-web-apps)