# Deploy django application on Microsoft Azure or Amazon Elastic Besanstalk

Tags: python, django, azure, python-3.4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a django (python) application. I wondered what is the best way to deploy it. With microsoft azure or Amazon Elastic Beanstalk ?

The application just needs to view data from a database. What are (dis)advantages of azure or elastic beanstalk?

I'm using OSX 10.9.5 and Python 3.4.3

Comment: You need to provide more details. As it stands now, this question is very difficult to answer and would most likely be closed as either "too broad" or "opinion based".

Comment: you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/#web-app-development---maclinux---command-line for a quick start

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav Mantri said, you need to provide more details - atleast the OS you are using. Some more surfing could lead you here :

[What's the recommended way to deploy a Django app on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731179/whats-the-recommended-way-to-deploy-a-django-app-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

For web apps, Azure has Azure App Service. Deployment can be done through a variety of ways, including FTP, git, or from Visual Studio. Since you're using Mac, I would recommend deploying via git.

To do so, first create a web app in the Azure portal, and then follow the steps here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

The advantages of Azure App Service, is that you can easily scale your app to many machines, and everything is taken care for you. Note that depending on how you've configured your database, you would have to deploy that separately.

Also, if you want to test Azure App Service, you can easily create a small sample Django application, using the Azure gallery. See the screen shot below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Apps provide a volume of ways for deployment your web applications. We can leverage tools/IDEs including FTP tools , Visual Studio and WebMatrix on Windows for remoting and modifying your web site code, and leverage repository for continuous deployment including local GIT, GITHUB, Visual Studio Online, Dropbox, Bitbucket.

It depends which way you prefer to.

As @ theadriangreen mentioned, Azure Web Apps provide Django template for a quick start, you can simply create a Django application and pull the code to local leveraging the methods above.

Beside [Continuous deployment using GIT in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/#web-app-development---maclinux---command-line), you also can refer to [Creating web apps with Django in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/#web-app-development---maclinux---command-line) for more information.